# using yaml for terraform tfvars

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Im using yaml with terraform, and im trying to retrieve values from yaml file.
This is my yaml file :

```
private_subnets :
  projectName1 :
    - cidr : "x.x.x.x/24"
      az : "us-east-2"
    - cidr : "x.x.x.x/24"
      az : "us-east-2"
  projectName2 :
    - cidr : "x.x.x.x/24"
      az : "us-east-2"
```

this is my terraform code :

```
  locals {
   priv_subnets = yamldecode(file("./subnets.yaml"))["projectName1"]
   priv_subnets_list = flatten([for subnet in local.priv_subnets :
    {
      "cidr"  =  subnet.cidr
      "az"    =  subnet.az 
    }
  ])
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
for_each = {
  for subnet in local.priv_subnets_list : subnet.cidr => subnet
}
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  availability_zone = each.value.az
}
```

Im able to create one resource at a time, do you see any options to optimize this code to **create both project1 and project2 subnets with the same aws resource ?** (the yaml file could have more projects in the future)

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You have to **flatten** your `private_subnets`, but a bit differently:

```
locals {
   priv_subnets = yamldecode(file("./subnets.yaml"))["private_subnets"]
   priv_subnets_list = merge([
     for project, subnets in local.priv_subnets: {
       for idx, subnet in subnets: 
         "${project}-${idx}" => {
            cidr  =  subnet.cidr
            az    =  subnet.az          
         }
     }
   ]...) # please, do NOT remove the dots
}
```

The above results in `priv_subnets_list` being:

```
{
  "projectName1-0" = {
    "az" = "us-east-2"
    "cidr" = "x.x.x.x/24"
  }
  "projectName1-1" = {
    "az" = "us-east-2"
    "cidr" = "x.x.x.x/24"
  }
  "projectName2-0" = {
    "az" = "us-east-2"
    "cidr" = "x.x.x.x/24"
  }
}
```

Then you use it as follows:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each          = local.priv_subnets_list 
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  availability_zone = each.value.az
}
```